# How to detect 'Enter' key on keyPress when used with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keypress, onkeypress

I am using ReactJs to develop my application. I am trying to submit an input text when Enter is pressed by handling the onKeyPress event. It detects other inputs, but not enter. I have tried different ways - `event.key`, `event.charCode`, `event.keyCode`, `event.which`... Nothing seems to work.

```
React.createElement("input", {tabIndex: "1", onKeyPress: this.handleKeyPress, onChange: this.handleChange, 
                           placeholder: "ex: 1,10,15"}), 

handleChange: function (event) {
        this.setState({userInputBuckets: event.target.value});
    },
handleKeyPress: function (event) {
        if (event.charCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.props.table.handleSubtotalBy(this.props.columnDef, this.state.userInputBuckets);
        }
    },
```

I also tried with `onKewDown` handling, it detects the correct key, but it doesn't execute the if block even though it evaluates `event.keyCode == 13` as true.

Comment: Is this input being created in a form? It might be firing the submit event instead of keypress.  Have you tried the keyDown event and seeing if it can capture the key stroke?

Comment: Yes, I tried with onKeyDown as well. It's bypassing the if block after evaluating the condition to true.

Comment: "it doesn't execute the if block even though it evaluates event.keyCode == 13 as true" that isn't right, unless you're using a very buggy JS engine. It's likely that the code inside throws an Error.

Comment: I tried that again. It executes the block, but results in an error at `event.stopPropogation()` at some other place where event is undefined.

Comment: OK. You'll need to post that part of the code to get some help.

Comment: `function ReactTableHandleSubtotalBy(columnDef, partitions, event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const subtotalBy = this.state.subtotalBy || [];
    ...}`
the function is called when handleSubtotalBy is called.

Answer (score 5):

Move `e.stopPropagataion` from `handleSubtotalBy` into `handleKeyPress`:

```
handleKeyPress(event) {
  if (event.charCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.props.table.handleSubtotalBy(this.props.columnDef, this.state.userInputBuckets);
  }
}


handleSubtotalBy(columnDef, partitions) { 
  const subtotalBy = this.state.subtotalBy || [];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped.

Comment: For others who are facing the same problem. Had to use `onKeyDown` instead of `onKeyPress`.

Answer (score 2):

[Given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958938/how-to-detect-enter-key-on-keypress-when-used-with-react/47581819#44959674) is not complete,

use

```
var code = event.keyCode || event.charCode
```

to support all browser:

Other than this, given answer is correct. Copy that.