# React Synthetic Event: How to capture if Enter key is pressed?

Tags: reactjs, enter, keycode, onkeyup

Why does the event passed below retain 'event.target' value but not 'event.code'?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { subscribeToTimer } from './api';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  function getInput(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.code);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <input type="text" name="message" className="message" placeholder="Type here..." onKeyUp={(e) => getInput(e)} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How do we capture the 'Enter' key pressed for the input element in React?!

Comment: Did you try searching stack overflow for similar questions before you posted this? I'm fairly sure this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [to call onChange event after pressing Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272207/to-call-onchange-event-after-pressing-enter-key)

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/44959674/9381601

Comment: Please read [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Comment: Keyboard events are described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events)

Comment: Yes indeed, but i didn't get the above in my search result. Now I'm thinking about the differences between e.code and e.key. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `code` key to the `event`.

You can use `event.key === 'Enter'` or `event.keyCode === 13` check if the key pressed is `Enter`.

Comment: DOM onkeyup event does have 'code' associated with it! 'event.code' does log 'Enter' when the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: But React Synthetic Event doesn't, hence my confusion :)